# Is there a certain size tube for my tyres?

Tags: tire

When it comes to fixing bikes, i'm not to crash-hot. I can clean grime, oil the chain and put it back on if it falls off. However, when it comes to the inner tubes I usually rely on someone else to get me another tube and put it on for me (I can put them on, but in that sense I'm too lazy). So, today, when I went to pump up the tyres I found they had a puncture and I would prefer to change them as I haven't ridden this bike in a LONG time, only I'm not sure if there has to be a certain size tube. Help? Please? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each tube reference size fits a certain number of tire sizes.
For example, I ride 700x23c tires and my tubes are 700-18-23c.

So just find out the size of your tire (should be written on the sidewall) and go out for a tube that will hav this tire size in its fitting range.

Be careful about the valve specification too. get a tube with the same valve type as your previous tube/as your wheel supports : http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_u-v.html#valve

Comment: Yep, and it should be added that often a tube will carry several size ratings -- eg, one for 700c tires and one for 27" tires.  You just need to match one set of the numbers.

Comment: Also, there is often some overlap in tube sizes. Common sizes are 18-23c and 23-35c.  You can use either one of those with a 23c tire, but the larger (23-25c) will probably be heavier, and will be streched less, which may give it a little more puncture protection. Although most of the puncture protection should come from the tire.  I've also seen 700xanything tubes, but I don't really understand how that works with everything from 23-38.  Of course larger and small sizes exist, but those ones seem to be the most common for bikes that aren't on a track.