# What inner tube should I buy for 47 tire size, 650bx47c tires?

Tags: tire, innertube, hybrid-bike, beginner

I'm pretty new on this and want to buy a spare inner tube. These are my specifications of the tires:

- Tire Size **47**
- Tires Maxxis DTR-1, **650b x 47c**
- Wheel Size **27.5**
- **Presta** valve

When I'm browsing, I see results like:

- Inner Tube - 650B/27.5" - 27.5" / 1.5" / 2.4" / Presta
- 650x28-42 Bike Inner Tube - Presta
- 27.5" x 1-1/2 (650x35) Presta Tube

But I have no idea what the **1.5"/2.4", 1-1/2**, etc. mean. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a certain size tube for my tyres?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/is-there-a-certain-size-tube-for-my-tyres)

Comment: I guess that 1-1/2 is a way of writing 1½ inch (same as 1.5").

Comment: The first rule of inch sizes in bicycle tires is that they are not same as the size of the actual tire. The second rule is that if there are two sizes that are the same number but one is written in decimals and other in fractions, they are not the same size.

Answer (score 5):

1.5"/2.4", 1-1/2 are the tyre width ranges the tube is compatible with. Your tyre size is indicated in mm (ETRTO standard sizing), but 47 mm is 1.85" so 1.5" / 2.4" is compatible.

The 650x28-42 is for narrower tyres. 1-1/2 (650x35) (1.5 inch, 35 mm)is likely too narrow as well, although one should check the actual lower and upper limits.